# Shared Storage Between Browser and Windows Worker Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, blazor-webassembly

I was looking for a way to share data between my browser and a windows worker service.

I want to have a shared storage place where a blazor wasm application writes a simple GUID and a c# windows worker service read it.

both worker service and blazor wasm are runinng on the same machine.

How can I do it?

Comment: have the Windows Service host an http listener on say: localhost:55555 and have your wasm app post the guid to localhost:55555 ?

Comment: Can Windows Service Host an Http or Https Listener?

Comment: Yes, why not? You might need some extra config to allow the service to listen on a port but it is not much different from say Internet Information Server. That also hosts a listener ...